# What is wrong with my implementation of: c# extension methods

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

the source is throwing the error:

```
'nn.asdf' does not contain a definition for 'extension_testmethod'
```

and i really don't unterstand why...

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System;

namespace nn
{
    public class asdf
    {
        public void testmethod()
        {
        }
    }
}
namespace nn_extension
{
    using nn;
    //Extension methods must be defined in a static class
    public static class asdf_extension
    {
        // This is the extension method.
        public static void extension_testmethod(this asdf str)
        {
        }
    }
}
namespace Extension_Methods_Simple
{
    //Import the extension method namespace.
    using nn;
    using nn_extension;
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            asdf.extension_testmethod();
        }
    }
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An extension method is a static method that behaves **like an instance method for the type being extended**, that is, you can call it on an instance of an object of type `asdf`. You can't call it as if it were a static method of the *extended* type.

Change your `Main` to:

```
asdf a = new asdf();
a.extension_testmethod();
```

Of course, you can always call like a simple, `static`, non-extension method of the *declaring* type (`asdf_extension`):

```
asdf_extension.extension_testmethod(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Extension methods apply to class instances:

```
var instance = new asdf();
instance.extension_testmethod();
```